# Calculate approxQuantile for a column of dataframe with a dot '.'

Tags: pyspark

I am not able to calculate approxQuantile for a pyspark dataframe containing a dot in the column name.

For e.g. dataframe schema is

```
root
 |-- col.dot: double (nullable = true)
```

Then I can't do

```
df.approxQuantile(('`col.dot`'), [0.5], 0.25)
```

It leads to the error:
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Field "`col.dot`" does not exist.\nAvailable fields: col.dot'

I have also tried

```
df.approxQuantile(('col.dot'), [0.5], 0.25)
```

which gives me the error as: 
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'cannot resolve \'`col.dot`\' given input columns: col.dot'

Answer (score 2):

Spark cannot resolve column names with dots  due to a bug (see this [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12965) for more information). Just use the code below to clean up your column names:

```py
x = [s.replace('.', 'DOT') for s in df.columns]
df = df.toDF(*x)
```